# How to use notifyDataSetChanged() in thread

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I create a thread to update my data and try to do `notifyDataSetChanged` at my ListView.

```
private class ReceiverThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() { 
    //up-to-date
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The error occurs at line:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Error**:

> 12-29 16:44:39.946: E/AndroidRuntime(9026): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

How should I modify it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `runOnUiThread()` method to execute the UI action from a Non-UI thread.

```
private class ReceiverThread extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() { 
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can not touch the views of the UI from other thread. For your problem you can use either **AsyncTask**, **runOnUiThread** or **handler**.

All The Best

Answer (score 4):

You cant access UI thread from other thread.You have to use handler to perform this.You can send message to handler inside your run method and update UI (call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()) inside handler.

Answer (score 1):

[access the UI thread from other threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)

> Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
>
> View.post(Runnable)
>
> View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

my approach whe i use other Threads for work:

```
private AbsListView _boundedView;
private BasicAdapter _syncAdapter;

 /** bind view to adapter */
public void bindViewToSearchAdapter(AbsListView view) {
    _boundedView = view;
    _boundedView.setAdapter(_syncAdapter);
}

/** update view on UI Thread */
public void updateBoundedView() {
    if(_boundedView!=null) {
        _boundedView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (_syncAdapter != null) {
                    _syncAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

btw **notifyDatasetChanged()** method hooks to  DataSetObservable class object of AbsListView which is set first by involving AbsListView.setAdaptert(Adapter) method by setting callback to Adapter.registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver);

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way also.

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    test();
                }
            }, 100);

private void test() {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

just test it.