# Cannot resolve method .runOnUiThread

Tags: android, listview

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665676/how-to-use-notifydatasetchanged-in-thread) example here on how to use the `runOnUiThread` method, but I don't understand how to use it.

I setup the list adapter in my main activity

```
    // Set a gobal reference to the list adapter and the list respectivly 

    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    static ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // some code

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_layout, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // some code

    }
```

I have the list adapter here calling a service handler class

```
public class ListAdapter {
    
    // some code

    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    sh.run();
}
```

Here is `.run()` method in `ServiceHandler` class where I updated the list and the list adapter

```
public void run(Adapter listAdapter, ArrayList<String> list){
    
    // some code

    list[0] = "foo";
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
}
```

But I get this error in run time

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

So I try to solve the error with `.runOnUiThread`

So here is `.run()` method in `ServiceHandler` class again, with `runOnUiThread`

```
public void run(Adapter listAdapter, ArrayList<String> list){
    
    // some code

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            list[0] = "foo";
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
    }});
}
```

But I get

> Cannot resolve method 'runOnUiThread(anonymous Java.lang.runnable)'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can move service handler as **private** member class inside your activity like below to use Activity's **this** context.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private class ServiceHandler /** Whichever class you extend */ {
        public void run() {
            MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });
        }
    }

    private MyListAdapterTracks mAdapter;

    private ServiceHandler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Some code

        mAdapter = new MyListAdapterTracks(getActivity(), R.layout.item_layout, list);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Some code

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        sh.run();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class ServiceHandler /** Whichever class you extend */ {

    private final Activity mActivity;

    private final MyListAdapterTracks mAdapter;

    public ServiceHandler(Activity activity, MyListAdapterTracks adapter) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
    }

    // More code

}
```

And then instanciate it in your activity like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyListAdapterTracks mAdapter;

    private ServiceHandler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Some code

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler(this);
        sh.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to move the service handler into the main activity.

Comment: In that case you can pass reference to your activity in ServiceHandler's constructor. See my edit above.

Comment: What does `private final Activity mActivity;` mean?

Comment: **private final** marks the private members as final, which means they cannot be re-assigned elsewhere the constructor.

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem, and I replaced `runOnUiThread()` with  `getActivity().runOnUiThread()`. And it worked.

Comment: What if I use adapter?