# RecyclerView: Race condition between notify* and scrollToPostion?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

**Is is possible to have race conditions between the `notify*` methods of a `RecyclerView.Adapter` and `scrollToPosition` (and `smoothScrollToPosition`) of the `RecyclerView` itself? If so, how can I force the `scroll` to happen strictly after the `notify` has been applied?**

In a bit more detail: I have a `RecyclerView` with an adapter that frequently is updated with new items (which may or may not overlap with the previous items). Also, whenever I set new items I also want to set the scroll position to a specific item. To that end, I first update the items inside my `Adapter` and then scroll the `RecyclerView`.

However, more often than not the scroll position will be wrong after this process. Also, if I then issue another `smoothScrollToPosition` command without changing the data, the scrolling is weird: It sometimes goes in the wrong direction, etc. After this second scrolling, the position is always correct however. So, it seems that something goes wrong the first time and the RecyclerView catches and corrects that error on the second scroll.

Also, the errors are slightly different when I use `notifyDataSetChanged` from when I use `DiffUtil`.

Now I've read in [this response by Yigit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512407/763935) that `notify*` is basically asynchronous, so I suppose there can be a race condition between them and the subseqent `scrollToPosition` - is that correct?

**Finally what can I do to establish a strict ordering, so that the scroll is only called when all ViewHolder updates triggered by notify are done?**

Comment: Partial answer: there is no race condition as everything related to the UI is run on the main/UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, Yigit's comment leads me to think that, even though everything happens on the main thread, *the order in which things happen* might still be undefined. Or can I be sure that all scrolling will happen after the View updates scheduled by `notify*` are carried out?